# Div Text Not Vertically Centered Only on Mac Browsers

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, vertical-alignment

I have an anchor tag with div and text. The text appears centered on Microsoft Windows browsers but are not vertically centered on Mac OS browsers, but strangely enough are centered on mobile browsers!

[image: IE 11[![][1]]
[image: Chrome OSX[![][2]]

CSS

```
.My-btn-orange {
     border-radius: 8px;
     background-color: #f2b943;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 23px;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-style: normal;
     font-stretch: normal;
     letter-spacing: normal;
     color: #fff;
     border: none;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 25px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="submitAddPrefsButton" onclick="submitSelection();return false;" class="My-btn-orange" style="cursor:pointer; width: 145px;"><span>SAVE</span></div>
```

Comment: I was editing your question to turn your CSS & HTML into a _Stack Snippet_ and quickly found that the markup & styles listed here are not sufficient to produce either of your images -- the text "SAVE" in the span was flush-left within the div (but it _was_ perfectly centered vertically in Chrome on Mac) You will need to provide a minimal example that looks like your captured image.

Comment: Your CSS value doesn't match with HTML tags - please provide matching values/tags.